# How to iterate over two lists using an index variable?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to deliver a list of sentences to a list of promises.

**Sentences Defintion:**

```
(def sentences (repeatedly promise))
(future
  (doseq [sentence (map deref sentences)]
    (println sentence)))
```

**Deliver:**

```
(doall (map deliver (nth sentences n) (parsedSentences)))
```

**Example:**

```
n = 1
parsedSentences = ["This is a sentence." "Is this a sentence?"]
```

I want to pass every entry of parsedSentences to a corresponding promise in sentences. Since I am very new to clojure I cant find a way to upcount `n`

I am looking for a way to do something like

```
deliver(nth sentences 1)("This is a sentence")
deliver(nth sentences 2)("Is this a sentence?")
...
deliver(nth sentences n)( sentence n)
```

So basically I am looking for a Clojure way to iterate over two lists using a index variable or something.

Comment: why don't you just map over both collections? (map deliver sentences parsedSentences) ?

Comment: @leetwinski thanks I didn't realize this is possible

Comment: Also please see `map-indexed` http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed

Comment: And also `indexed` from the Medley lib:  http://weavejester.github.io/medley/medley.core.html#var-indexed

Comment: @leetwinski that is an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have already half-written the answer yourself, except that you wrote `(nth sentences n)` (a thing which is clearly impossible, as you know `n` is not in scope) instead of just `sentences`.

The `map` function is most commonly called with exactly one sequence argument, but when called with more than one it acts as `zipWith` in some other languages, returning `[(f x0 y0) (f x1 y1) (f x2 y2) ...]`. You can even call `map` with zero sequence arguments, and then it's a transducer instead.

So, you would simply write

```
(map deliver sentences parsedSentences)
```

Comment: You are right and acutally after asking my question I did exactly this, but in my special case this did not work because I am using an endless list where the index has to grow.

 In the end I used the following code.

(def sentences (repeatedly promise))
(def sentenceCounter 0)

(doseq [sentence parsedSentences] (deliver (nth sentences sentenceCounter) sentence) (def sentenceCounter (inc sentenceCounter )))

Maybe you can put my code in your answer, than I will mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Map-indexed is probably what you're looking for. The function it takes has two params so something along the lines of `(fn [idx, el] (dosomething idx el)`. I believe you can also map over multiple collections at once and each set of elements will be delivered as a tuple like `(c1e1, c2e1,..., cNe1)` (c for collection and e for element ordinality within that collection).

```
clojure.core/map-indexed
([f] [f coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to 0
  and the first item of coll, followed by applying f to 1 and the second
  item in coll, etc, until coll is exhausted. Thus function f should
  accept 2 arguments, index and item. Returns a stateful transducer when
  no collection is provided.
```